# If Else Gravatar Author Picture

Tags: author, user-meta, gravatar

Ok so i have added a custom field inside of the WordPress edit profile field where a contributor and above can add a custom image if they do not use gravatar. Now i am trying to write a if else statement and this is what i have

```
<?
    $hasauthorpic = (the_author_meta('author_pic'));
    if (function_exists('get_avatar')) { echo get_avatar( get_the_author_email(), '80' );}
    else {echo '?><img class="avatar avatar-80 photo"><? $hasauthorpic ?></img><? ';}
?>
```

What i want to try and do is if the user does have a gravatar use it unless they have specified a link to there profile pic. Or have the author_pic become higher priority even if user has gravatar.

**EDIT:**

```
<?
$authorpic = the_author_meta('author_pic');
$gravatar = get_avatar( get_the_author_email(), '80' );
    if ($authorpic); 
    elseif (function_exists('get_avatar')) 
            echo ($gravatar); 
?>
```

OK so i tried the code below and that did not quite work. Maybe because i am putting this into a single-whatever.php file. The above is what i have managed to get but the only problem is when it shows it shows both the avatar and author pic link so i know i still need to add the `<img>` tags but that will be easy later. The one thing i did read is that your cant put a `true` on `the_author_meta` so i need help.

If you can come up with a code to hook into the gravatar stuff then ill take it. In other words if you have a code that i can place in my functions.php file thatll work to i and i would prefer that. the field name is `author_pic`

**UPDATE:** This is my final write up with the provided code from below

```
<?php
$authorpic = get_the_author_meta('author_pic');
$imgtagbeg = ('<img style="height:80px; width:80px" src="');
$imgtagend = ('"/>');
if ($authorpic)
    echo $imgtagbeg,$authorpic,$imgtagend; 
else
    echo get_avatar( get_the_author_email(), '80' ); 
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use get_the_author_meta() instead of the_author_meta()

```
<?php
$authorpic = get_the_author_meta('author_pic');
if ($authorpic)
    echo $authorpic; 
else
    echo get_avatar( get_the_author_email(), '80' ); 
?>
```

Comment: can you explain how the get_the_author_meta will show the image when that is meant for displaying none

Comment: echo $authorpic; will echo whatever you are storing in the author_pic author meta field.

Comment: I did use this but changed the code a bit. Ill post my final solution above in my question but mark your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` will always return true and bypass your custom author pic.

Run the if on the custom field.  If it returns true then add a filter to get_avatar that uses the custom field author pic.

```
if ( the_author_meta('author_pic') ) {
add_filter( 'get_avatar', 'your_custom_author_pic_function' );
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. Still Learning.

Comment: Ok so what about adding an `<img>` tag for the author pic where do i insert this

Comment: In your custom function.  Take a look at [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17413/) for more details on filtering get_avatar.

Comment: ok but this is not a custom function unless it would work better that way. I simply have it in a template page

Comment: Ok so i updated my original question maybe you can take a look at it

Answer (score 2):

There is a sweet new plugin I recently discovered called [Simple Local Avatars](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-local-avatars/) that will do exactly what you ask. Check it out!

Comment: seen it. not what i want i do not want my users uploading pics. and i would prefer a hard code solution

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correct, you don't want people to upload a custom avatar, but you do want people to be able to link to a custom avatar? (and, if not, a default avatar or gravatar kicks in)
If that's the case, this article will probably suit your needs http://www.billerickson.net/wordpress-custom-avatar/

Comment: i have already got this working. as well the user will not be able to link to any image. I use my own url and the server checks for the image based of of there username